# ajax onchange username validation and brute force attacks

Tags: php, ajax

I have created ajax onchange validation for username. If user enters username that already exists or contains invalid characters or is shorter, etc. then immediately gets warning: username already exists/contains invalid characters/is shorter than...

Ajax onchange takes user input, with php validates.

Now I am thinking. In such way possible brute force attackers easy can get information about existing usernames...? Or no danger....?

Comment: Brute forcing would require him to try and login. Make sure you limit the number of failed logins.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially how all username validation requests work is by sending a request to a server. Just because you are using AJAX here does not make it any more susceptible to Brute Force attacks.

However keep a few things in mind
like @NickFury said, make sure you have a have a retry limit. Maybe use an exponentially increasing time for password retries.

Enforcing a good password size limit and other guidelines along with a retry limit would make brute-force practically impossible. *However* if the user decides to use `welcome` as his/her password thats their fault.

But make sure you never store passwords in your database as plain text. Always use something like BCrypt.

Comment: Retry limit for login? Yes, I will create.....Or may be to use something for username.. for example if visitor typed allowed username but do not choose it and instead type other username (several times)... to disallow it. Or it is useless?

Comment: Trust me you are overthinking it. If you enforce a good password limit (at least 6) brute forcing a good password with a retry-limit would be practically impossible, if that's what your concern is.

Comment: ok:), yes, may be paranoid.... reading about so much dangers....instead of writing actual script, need to think about all these hackers...